# A conjectured formula for Apéry numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, harmonic-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

A conjecture by the late Romanian mathematician Alexandru Lupas.
Posted in [sci.math](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3704516) in 2005, but no proof was found.
Physicist [Alan Sokal](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/faculty/sokal/) just reminded me of it, saying it was related to something he is working on.

Let $P_n(z)$ be the Legendre polynomials, defined by the generating function
$$
\big(1-2tz+t^2\big)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k P_k(z) .
$$
Let $g(\alpha,\beta) = 4\cos(2\alpha)+8\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)+5$ be defined for 
$(\alpha,\beta) \in (-\pi,\pi)\times (-\pi,\pi)$ .  Let $A_n$ be these [Apéry numbers](http://oeis.org/A005259)
$$
A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^3 .
$$

**examples**
$$
P_0(z)=1;\qquad
P_1(z)=z;\qquad
P_2(z)=\frac{3}{2}\;z^2-\frac{1}{2};\qquad
P_3(z)=\frac{5}{2}\;z^3-\frac{3}{2}\;z;
\\
A_0 = 1;\qquad A_1=5;\qquad A_2=73;\qquad A_3=1445;\qquad A_4=33001 .
$$

**Prove or disprove:**
$A_n$ is the average of $P_n\circ g$.  More explicitly:  for all natural numbers $n$,
$$
A_n = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi 
P_n\big(g(\alpha,\beta)\big)\;d\beta\;d\alpha
$$

This is surely true (Sokal says he has checked it through $n=123$).  But can **you** prove it?

**additional notes**

Also
$$
A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{n}^2\binom{n+k}{k}^2
$$
The conjecture should be equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d\alpha\;d\beta}{\sqrt{
t^2-2t(4\cos(2\alpha)+8\sin\beta\cos\alpha+5)+1}\;}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k t^k
$$
In the integral we can change variables to get
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{dp\;dq}{\sqrt{1-p^2}
\sqrt{1-q^2}\sqrt{1-2t(8pq+8q^2+1)+t^2}\;}
$$

Comment: I believe the formula should read $$A_n = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{\color{red}-\pi}^\pi 
P_n\big(g(\alpha,\beta)\big)\;d\beta\;d\alpha$$

Comment: Just a suggestion, Wadim Zudilin quit MO some time ago; he is a CARMA at Newcastle, Australia. His sort of thing. I write to him with questions occasionally, he sends brief answers or references. Has a new book with Shallit and Borwein   http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions

Comment: @Will, my late colleague, Alf van der Poorten, is also credited as an author of that book.

Comment: @Gerry, yes, I was going to mention him and found that I could not be sure of the spelling. It seems quite a good book, I will probably buy it, I don't buy many books these days.

Comment: See the follow-up question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179108/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here as an approach. 
It is known that:
$P_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n-1}{k}\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^{k}$  (see for example  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)
Therefore these expressions are equal 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}^{3}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n-1}{k}\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1-g(x,y)}{2}\right)^{k}dydx
$$
if 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}^{3}=\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{g(x,y)-1}{2}\right)^{k}dydx
$$
One can see that 
$$
\left(\frac{g(x,y)-1}{2}\right)^{k} = 4^{k} (\cos^{2}x + \cos x \sin y )^k
$$
Therefore we get 
$$
\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{g(x,y)-1}{2}\right)^{k}dydx = \frac{4^k}{4\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}\cos^{2k-j}x \sin^{j} y dxdy
$$

Since 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{m} x dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^{m} x dx = \frac{2\pi} {2^m}\binom{m}{m/2} \quad \text{for} \quad m \quad \text{even, otherwise =0}
\end{align*}
We get 
$$
\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{g(x,y)-1}{2}\right)^{k}dydx  = \sum_{\ell=0}^{k/2}\binom{k}{2\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\binom{2(k-\ell)}{k-\ell}
$$

and now we want to show that 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}^{3}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{k/2}\binom{k}{2\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\binom{2(k-\ell)}{k-\ell}
$$
The last equality follows from the identity:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}^{3}=\sum_{\ell=k/2}^{k}\binom{k}{\ell}^{2}\binom{2\ell}{k}
$$ 
See for example http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311195v1.pdf formula (2).
because 
$$
\binom{k}{2\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\binom{2k-2\ell}{k-\ell}=\binom{k}{k-\ell}^{2}\binom{2k-2\ell}{k}
$$

Comment: The identity involving $\sum_j {k \choose j}^3$ can also be proved by observing that both sides satisfy the recursion $(8k^2+32k+32)f(k+1) + (7k^2+35k+44)f(k+2) -(k^2+6k+9)f(k+3)$ and have the same initial values, where the recursion can be found by standard techniques (e.g., $\mathtt{listtorec}$ in Maple's $\mathtt{gfun}$ package).

Comment: Another proof : $\sum_{j} \binom{k}{j}^3 = \sum_r \binom{k}{r} \binom{k}{k-r} \binom{k}{r} = \sum_r \sum_t \binom{k}{r}\binom{k}{k-r}\binom{r}{t}\binom{k-r}{t} = \sum_r\sum_t \binom{k}{t}\binom{k-t}{r-t}\binom{k}{t}\binom{k-t}{k-r-t}= \sum_{t} \binom{k}{t}^2 \sum_r \binom{k-t}{r-t}\binom{k-t}{k-r-t} = \sum_{u} \binom{k}{u}^2 \sum_r \binom{u}{k-r}\binom{u}{r} = \sum_u \binom{k}{u}^2 \binom{2u}{k} = \sum_u \binom{k}{u} \binom{2u}{u} \binom{u}{k-u} = \sum_\ell \binom{k}{\ell}\binom{2(k-\ell)}{k-\ell} \binom{k-\ell}{\ell}  = \sum_\ell \binom{k}{2\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\binom{2(k-\ell)}{k-\ell}.$