# Is the sequence of Apéry numbers a Stieltjes moment sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the sequence of [Apéry numbers](http://oeis.org/A005259)
$$
A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^3
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2\binom{n+k}{k}^2 .
$$
In an email, physicist [Alan Sokal](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/faculty/sokal/) conjectures that it is a [Stieltjes moment sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem).  That is, that there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,+\infty)$ so that
$$
A_n = \int_{[0,+\infty)} s^n\;d\mu(s)
\tag{1}$$
for $n = 0,1,2,\dots$.  [Of course you can equivalently say that $\mu$ is a nondecreasing function with $\mu(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \mu(s) = 1$ and that (1) is a Stieltjes integral, rather than a "measure" integral.]

**Is that conjecture correct?  Is $A_n$ a Stieltjes moment sequence?**

[This question is a follow-up to [A conjectured formula for Apéry numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178790/) , where a formula for $A_n$ was established.]

Comment: http://oeis.org/A228143

Comment: I think there is some hope to determine a solution, and I'll try some computations.

Comment: I observed the following fact. Consider the following second order linear ODE with polynomial coefficients:
$$(4x^3-136x^2+4x)u''+(8x^2-204x+4)u'+(x-10)u=0.$$
Assume that $u$ is a solution on $(0,+\infty)$, with $u(0)=0$ and $u(x)=o(x^{-n})$ for all natural $n$, and normalized so that $\int_0^\infty u^2dx=1$. Then, the measure $\mu$ with density $d\mu= u^2dx$ has the Apery numbers as a sequence of moments.

Comment: (I'm just not completely sure that such a solution $u$ does exist)

Comment: The series solution for that ODE shows that the only solution with $u(0)=0$ is the identically zero solution.  Where did this ODE come from?  The recurrence for $A_n$?

Comment: Exact, from the recurrence of $A_n$ I got a third order linear ODE for a density $w=d\mu/dx$. Trying to prove the existence of a positive solution, i.e. $w=u^2$, I noticed that $u$ would satisfy the above *second* order ODE. I do not know what that means, but seems remarkable. However, I agree that the latter has no nontrivial bounded solutions, but there is another remark:

Comment: From the recurrence of the $A_n$ we have $A_n=O(c^n)$ where $c:=17+12\sqrt{2}$ is the larger root of $x^2-34x+1$. Therefore, the measure $\mu$ has support in the interval $[0,c]$ (so we are dealing with the Hausdorff moment problem, and the measure is unique). Moreover, the above linear equation should be studied on $[0,c]$. The series solution with $u(0)=0$ has convergence radius $1/c$ (in fact $1/c$ is the other root).

Comment: So my guess is: the measure $\mu$ has a.c. part with density $u^2$ for some solution $u$ of the above ODE, maybe singular at $0, 1/c$ or $c$, plus possibly some deltas at these points. And maybe it is a measure on $[1/c,c]$.

Comment: This is interesting.  Maple solves that ODE in terms of the "Heun G" function.  And $1/c$ and $c$ correspond to two of the defining singularities of the HG that we get.  Maple's support for HG is rather limited, though, so I have to work to get information.

Comment: @Pietro: Would you like to add a (partial) answer showing your derivation of the ODE.  The set of solutions on $(1/c,c)$ is 2-dimensional, so for this to work we will need some way to pick the right one.  I think we cannot get both ends going to zero, however.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it in a couple of days (I'm on travel now).

Comment: Another remark: it seems to me that in fact  $A(n)=o(c^n)$. Is it true? In this case, $w$ should vanish at $c$.

Comment: It is $o(c^n)$, but that does not make the density vanish at the endpoint.  Try density $1$ on $[0,1]$: the moments are $1/(n+1) = o(1)$, but $1$ does not vanish at the endpoint.

Comment: Good point,  $o(c^n)$ just tells $\mu(\{c\})=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some computations that may be useful. Here below, $\big[ \,f\,\big]_a^b$ denotes $f(b)-f(a)$, and $n^{(k)}:=n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)$.

**1. (An integration by parts).** *Let $w$ be a solution of the third order linear ODE on the interval $[a,b]$:
$$(x^4-34x^3+x^2)w''' + 3(2x^3-51x^2+x)w''+(7x^2-112x+1)w'+(x-5)w=0,$$
and put $$M(n):=\int_a^b x^nw(x)dx$$ for any integer $n\ge0$.
Then, for any $n\ge 2$, 
$$n^3M(n)- (34n^3-51n^2+27n-5)M(n-1) + (n-1)^3M(n-2)= \Big[A(x)(x^n)''  + B(x)(x^n)' + C(x)x^n  \Big]_a^b,$$
where 
$$ A:=pw  \qquad   B:=  qw- (pw)'  \qquad C:=   (pw )''   -  (qw)'+ rw   ,$$
and* $$p(x):=x^3-34x^2+x\qquad q(x):=3x^2-51x\qquad r(x):=x+10-x^{-1}.$$

**Proof**. We express the above polynomials of $n$ in the base  $n^{(k)}$,   then we absorb the latter terms as coefficients of   derivatives of $x^n$, and finally we integrate by parts.

We have:
$$n^3M(n)- (34n^3-51n^2+27n-5)M(n-1) + (n-1)^3M(n-2)=$$
$$\int_a^b\Big\{n^3x^nw -(34n^3-51n^2+27n-5)x^{n-1}w   +(n-1)^3x^{n-2}w\Big\}dx=$$
$$\int_a^b\Big\{(n^ {(3)}+3n^ {(2)}+ n)x^nw -(34n^{(3)}+51n ^{(2)}+10n-5)x^{n-1}w   +(n^{(3)}+n-1)x^{n-2}w\Big\}dx=$$
$$\int_a^b\Big\{(x^n)'''pw+(x^n)''qw+(x^n)'rw+x^n(5x^{-1} -x^{-2} )w\}dx=$$
$$ \int_a^bx^n \Big\{-(pw)'''+(qw)''-(rw)'+ (5x^{-1} -x^{-2} )w\}dx
+\Big[ (x^n)''pw- (x^n)'(pw)'+ x^n(pw)'' +(x^n)'qw-x^n(qw)'   +rw \Big]_a^b=$$
$$ -\int_a^bx^{n-1} \Big\{(x^4-34x^3+x^2)w''' + 3(2x^3-51x^2+x)w''+(7x^2-112x+1)w'+(x-5)w\Big\}dx+$$
$$+\Big[ (x^n)''pw+  (x^n)'\big(qw- (pw)'\big)+ x^n\big( (pw )''   -  (qw)'+ rw \big)  \Big]_a^b=$$
$$=\Big[A(x)(x^n)''  + B(x)(x^n)' + C(x)x^n  \Big]_a^b.\qquad\square$$

**2.(Consequence).** *Let $w$ a   solution of the above linear equation on $(0,c)\setminus\{c_0\}$, with $\int_0^c w(x)dx=1$, and and assume it verifies the following linear boundary conditions, expressed in terms of the above coefficients $A,B,C$:*

i)   $A(x)=o(1),\quad B(x)=o(1),\quad C(x)=O(1)$, as $x\to0$;

ii)   $A(x),\quad B(x),\quad C(x)$, are continuous at $x=c_0$ ,

iii) $A(x)=o(1) ,\quad  B(x)=o(1) ,\quad  C(x)=o(1)$, as $x\to c$.

*Then the corresponding $M(n)$ are the Apéry sequence.*

Indeed, computing the integral on $[0,c]$ for $M(n)$ as limit of integrals on $[\epsilon, c_0-\epsilon]\cup[c_0+\epsilon, c-\epsilon]$ as $\epsilon\to0$, and applying the above integration by parts formula, one gets that $M(n)$ satisfy the Apéry's recurrence, with $M(0)=1$ (note that $M(1)=5M(0)$ follows from the recurrence as  well).

**rmk.** *This also include the case where $w$ vanishes   identically on $(0,c_0)$, and the condition is simply that $A, B, C$ should vanish both at $x=c_0$ and  at $x=c$*.

**3. (Positive solutions of the third order ODE).** *Assume $u$ solves the second order linear ODE 
$$(x^3-34x^2+x)u''+(2x^2-51x+1)u'+\frac{1}{4}(x-10)u=0.$$
Then $w:=u^2$ solves*
$$(x^4-34x^3+x^2)w''' + 3(2x^3-51x^2+x)w''+(7x^2-112x+1)w'+(x-5)w=0.$$

**Proof**. Put $$P:=x^4-34x^3+x^2\qquad Q:=\frac{x^2}{2}-5x,$$
so the equation for $u$ (multiplied by $2x$) writes:
$$2Pu''+P'u'+Qu=0,$$
and we have
$$0=(2Pu''+P'u'+Qu)'u+ 3(2Pu''+P'u'+Qu)u'=$$
$$=(2Pu'''+2P'u''+P'u''+P''u'+Qu'+Q'u)u+3(2Pu''+P'u'+Qu)u'=$$
$$=P(2u'''u+6u''u')+3P'(u''u+u'^2)+(P''+4Q)u'u+Q'u^2=$$
$$=Pw''' +\frac{3}{2}P'w''+\Big(\frac{P''}{2}+2Q\Big)w'+Q'w,$$
which is the above third order equation for $w$.

Comment: The next step should be,  checking if the boundary conditions in **2** are compatible with the solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$. And, of course, if they are in $L^2$.  Note that (iii) would be satisfied if $u(c)=0$  because $c$ is then a root of $pw$, $qw$, $rw$ with multiplicity resp. $3,2,2$. Unfortunately this w.e. I'm in a place with no Maple!

Comment: I noticed something else.  According to the OEIS listing, $A_n = O(c^n/n^{3/2})$.  If $w$ has a nonzero limit at $c$, we would only get $O(c^n/n)$ for the moments.  So we need a $w$ to have a singularity like $(c-x)^{1/2}$ at $x=c$.  Fortunately, that is compatible with the 3rd-order DE (but not with being a square of a solution of the 2nd-order DE).

Comment: My computation says, for a solution of the 3rd-order DE, the boundary terms in the integration by parts will cancel at $c_o$ and at $c$.  (The individual terms don't cancel, but taken together they do.) So I'm thinking of using interval $(c_o,c)$ and not trying the tricky thing of going down to $0$.

Comment: I thought each term $A(x), B(x), C(x)$ should  vanish at $x=0$ and $x=c$, and be continuous at $x=c_0$, in order that the boundary terms cancel, because they are coefficients with different powers of $n$ in front.  

Also, by linearity $2u_1u_2=((u_1+u_2)^2-u_1^2-u_2^2$ is also a solution of the 3rd order DE, so we have $3$ linearly independent solutions ODE.

Comment: But yes, $(c_0,c)$ would make everything nicer. (btw the 2-order DE can be written in a form of Sturm-Liouville operator, $(gu')'+hu=0$, dividing $2Pu''+P'u'+Qu=0$ by  $|P|^{1/2}$ ).

Comment: I am not so sure any longer that the boundary terms all vanish.  Maybe we do have to go down to zero.  But there are logarithmic singularities there.

Comment: Well, logarithmic is not bad -- I was scared of stronger singularities that could make $u^2$ non-integrable...

Comment: I accepted this answer.  But anyone reading should see the other answers, too, to get a full discussion.

Answer (score 11):

I think the conjecture is true.

Below is an outline of a proof strategy---however, carefully verification of the details remains. If I find more time, I can try to fill those in (or maybe someone else provides a different proof before that).

> For $\{A_n\}$ to be a Stieltjes-Moment sequence, two matrices $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ must be positive definite.

The matrix $\Delta$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
  \Delta :=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A_0 & A_1 & \cdots & A_n\\
    A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_{n+1}\\
     & \vdots &  & \\
     A_n & A_{n+1} & \cdots & A_{2n}
  \end{pmatrix},\quad\text{i.e.}\quad \Delta_{ij} = A_{i+j-2}, 1\le i,j \le n+1,
\end{equation*}
while the matrix $\Delta' := [\Delta'_{ij}] = [A_{i+j-1}]$ for $1 \le i,j \le n+1$.

We prove below that $\Delta$ is symmetric positive semidefinite (a brief additional argument should establish strict positivity, which is what is needed to ensure infinite support).

First, we write $A_n$ using slightly different notation:
\begin{equation*}
  A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n,k}^2,\qquad a_{n,k} := \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}.
\end{equation*}
Next, define the order-0 Schmidt numbers
\begin{equation*}
  S_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n,k},
\end{equation*}
and consider the matrix $M$ formed like $\Delta$ except that instead of $A_n$ we use $S_n$. We begin by proving that $S_n$ is positive definite, in particular by showing that
\begin{equation*}
  S_{i+j-2} = \langle \phi(i), \phi(j) \rangle,
\end{equation*}
for some $\phi$. A similar  (though more involved) technique can be followed for $A_n$ (though, if we actually could represent $a_{i+j-2,k}$ as an inner product, then the proof for $A_n$ would follow immediately using the Schur-product theorem).

The key trick is to use the ``symmetric'' form of the Vandermonde-Chu identity:
\begin{equation*}
  \binom{r+s}{k} = \sum_{p,q \ge 0; p+q=k}\binom{r}{p}\binom{s}{q}.
\end{equation*}
Applying this identity, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \binom{i+j-2}{k} &=& \sum_{p,q\ge 0, p+q=k} \binom{i-1}{p}\binom{j-1}{q}\\
  \binom{i+j-2+k}{k} &=& \sum_{p,q\ge 0, p+q=k} \binom{i-1+k/2}{p}\binom{j-1+k/2}{q}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\binom{n}{j} = 0$ for $j > n$, we drop the summation indices (unless needed), and obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
  M_{ij} &=& \sum_{k}\biggl( \sum_{\substack{p,q \ge 0\\ p+q=k}} \binom{i-1}{p}\binom{j-1}{q} \biggr) \biggl( \sum_{p,q \ge 0, p+q=k} \binom{i-1+k/2}{p}\binom{j-1+k/2}{q}\biggr)\\
  &=& \sum_k\sum_{\substack{p,q\ge 0, p+q=k\\ r,s \ge0, r+s=k}}\binom{i-1}{p}\binom{i-1+k/2}{r}\binom{j-1}{q}\binom{j-1+k/2}{s}\\
  &=& \sum_{p,r,q, s \ge 0}\psi(i; p,r) \psi(j; q,s),\\
  &=& \langle \psi(i), \psi(j) \rangle,
\end{eqnarray*}
for suitably defined $\psi(i; p, r)$. This proves that $M$ is a Gram matrix, hence positive definite.

In a similar way, we can prove that $\Delta_{ij} = \sum_k a_{i+j-2,k}^2 = \langle \phi(i), \phi(j)\rangle$ for a suitable mapping $\phi$, thus establishing positive definiteness of $\Delta$.

Continuing along this path, we can similarly prove $\Delta'$ is also positive definite, which will then finally establish the conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

Some information on Pietro's ODE:
$$
(4x^3-136x^2+4x)u''+(8x^2-204x+4)u'+(x-10)u=0
\tag{1}$$
I will use this notation:
$$
c := (1+\sqrt{2}\;)^4 = 17+12\sqrt{2} \approx 33.97056 ,
\\
c_o := \frac{1}{c} = 34-c = 17-12\sqrt{2} \approx 0.02944 ,
\\
a := 1-c^2 = -576-408\sqrt{2} \approx -1159.9991 ,
\\
q := -\frac{11317}{4}-234\sqrt{2} \approx -660.176 ,
\\
\alpha := \frac{3}{2}, \beta := \frac{3}{2}, \gamma := \frac{3}{2}, 
\delta := 1, \epsilon := \frac{3}{2} .
$$
Maple converts $(1)$ to a Heun differential equation, and evaluates it in terms of the Heun functions.  See [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31) for information on that.  I will follow their notation.  In interval $(c_o,c)$, two linearly independent solutions of $(1)$ are
$$
u_1(x) := (x-c_o)^{1/2}(c-x)^{1/2} Hl\big(a,q;\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta;1-cx\big)
\\
= \sqrt {-{x}^{2}+34\,x-1}\;{\it Hl} \left( -408\,\sqrt {2}-576,-234\,
\sqrt {2}-{\frac {1317}{4}};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},1,-17\;x-12\,x\sqrt {2}+1 \right) 
\\
u_2(x) := (c-x)^{1/2} Hl\big(a,(a\delta+\epsilon)(1-\gamma)+q;\alpha+1-\gamma,\beta+1-\gamma,2-\gamma,\delta;1-cx\big)
\\
= \sqrt {-x+17+12\,\sqrt {2}}\;
{\it Hl} \left( -408\,\sqrt {2}-576,-42-30\,\sqrt {2},1,1,\frac{1}{2},1,-17
\,x-12\,x\sqrt {2}+1 \right) 
$$
The endpoints $x=c_o$ and $x=c$ correspond to $1-cx$ at the Heun singularities $0$ and $a$, respectively.

Here is a graph of $u_1(x)$

[image: u1 all]

At the left end, $x=c_o$, it goes to zero, but has a vertical tangent (like a square-root)

[image: u1 left]

At the right end, $x=c$, it goes to a finite limit, but has a vertical tangent

[image: u1 right]

The wiggles are not real, but show Maple's difficulty in evaluating close to the singularity.

Here is a graph of $u_2(x)$

[image: u2 all]

At the left end $x=c_o$ it approaches a definite value $2^{7/4}3^{1/2}$ with a non-vertical tangent

[image: u2 left]

and at the right end $x=c$ it approaches a definite value with vertical tangent

[image: u2 right]

For some linear combinations of $u_1$ and $u_2$ the square-root term cancels and it approaches a definite limit at $x=c$ with non-zero tangent.  But for those, the approach at $x=c_o$ has vertical tangent.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will take into account carefully the boundary terms in the integration by parts that produces the ODE for the weight: I think that a singularity at $c_0$ may not be a problem, and $u(0)=0$ is not necessarily required, but the solution should verify some suitable linear boundary conditions at $0$, $c_0$, and $c$.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is my current thinking on Pietro's approach.

We use the differential equation
$$
(x^4-34x^3+x^2)U'''(x) + 3(2x^3-51x^2+x)U''(x)+(7x^2-112x+1)U'(x)+(x-5)U(x)=0
\tag{ODE3}$$
Multiply by $x^k$, $k \ge 0$, then integrate by parts as much as possible.  The result is
$$
\int \!{x}^{k-1} \left( {k}^{3}{x}^{2}-34\,{k}^{3}x
+3\,{k}^{2}{x}^{2}+{k}^{3}-51\,{k}^{2}x+3\,k{x}^{2}-27\,kx+{x}^{2}-5\,
x \right) U \left( x \right) {dx}
=
 \left( {x}^{k+2}{k}^{2}-34\,{x}^{1+k}{k}^{2}+{x}^{k+2}k+{x}^{k}{k}^{2
}-17\,{x}^{1+k}k+{x}^{k+2}-10\,{x}^{1+k} \right) U \left( x \right)
 +
 \left( -{x}^{1+k}k-{x}^{3+k}k+34\,{x}^{k+2}k+{x}^{1+k}+2\,{x}^{3+k}-
51\,{x}^{k+2} \right) U' \left( x \right)
 + 
\left( {x}^{k+4}-34\,{x}^{3+k}+{x}^{k+2} \right) U'' \left( x \right)
\tag{A}$$
In particular, for $k=0$,
$$
\int (x-5)U(x)\;dx
=
\left( {x}^{2}-10\,x \right) U \left( x \right) + \left( 2\,{x}^{3}-
51\,{x}^{2}+x \right) U' \left( x \right) + \left( {x}^{
4}-34\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2} \right) U'' \left( x
 \right)
\tag{A0}$$
Write $Q_k(x)$ for the right-hand-side of (A) and $\int R_k(x)U(x)\;dx$ for the left side.  We will be doing differences like
$$
\big[Q_k(x)\big]_a^b := Q_k(b)-Q_k(a)
$$
since that will equal the integral on the left $\int_a^b R_k(x)U(x)\;dx$.
We want to arrange a solution $U$ so that $\int_0^c R_k(x)U(x)\;dx=0$ for $k \ge 0$.  As Pietro noted, this will give us the recurrence we want for the moments $M(k):=\int_0^c x^kU(x)\;dx$.  And in particular from (A0) we would have $\int_0^c (x-5)U(x)\;dx = 0$ so that $M(1)=5M(0)$.

Now consider (ODE3).  First look at solutions as we approach $x=c$ from the left.  Three linearly independent solutions are asymptotically: $1$, $(c-x)^{1/2}$, $(c-x)$.  Other terms are higher powers (integer and half-integer).  My calculations show:

for the term $1$, we get $Q_k(c^-)=1/2\, \left( 24+17\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( 24\,k+24+7\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( 17+12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k}$

for the term $(c-x)^{1/2}$, we get $Q_k(c^-)=0$, amazingly

for the term $(c-x)$, we get $Q_k(c^-)=\left( -9792-6924\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( 17+12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k}$

terms $(c-x)^2$ and higher all produce $Q_k(c^-)=0$.

Now look at solutions as we approach $x=c_o$ from the right.  Three linearly independent soltuions are asymptotically: $1$, $(x-c_o)^{1/2}$, $(x-c_o)$.

for the term $1$, we get $Q_k(c_o^+)=1/2\, \left( 17\,\sqrt {2}-24 \right)  \left( -24\,k-24+7\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( 17-12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k}$

for the term $(x-c_o)^{1/2}$, we get $Q_k(c_o^+)=0$

for the term $(x-c_o)$, we get $Q_k(c_o^+)=-12\,\sqrt {2} \left( 17-12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k+2}$

for higher terms, we get $Q_k(c_o^+)=0$

Now look at solutions as we approach $x=c_o$ from the left.  Three linearly independent soltuions are asymptotically: $1$, $(c_o-x)^{1/2}$, $(x-c_o)$.

for the term $1$, we get $Q_k(c_o^-)=1/2\, \left( 17\,\sqrt {2}-24 \right)  \left( -24\,k-24+7\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( 17-12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k}$

for the term $(c_o-x)^{1/2}$, we get $Q_k(c_o^-)=0$

for the term $(x-c_o)$, we get $Q_k(c_o^-)=-12\,\sqrt {2} \left( 17-12\,\sqrt {2} \right) ^{k+2}$

for higher terms, we get $Q_k(c_o^-)=0$

Now look at terms as we approach $x=0$ from the right.  Three linearly independent terms are asymptotically: $1$, $\log x$, $(\log x)^2$.

for the term $1$, we get $Q_k(0^+)=0$

for the term $\log x$, we get $Q_k(0^+)=0$

for the term $(\log x)^2$, we get $Q_k(0^+)=0$ for $k \ge 1$ but $Q_0(0^+)=2$

for higher terms (such as $x$, $x\log x$, etc.), we get $Q_k(0^+)=0$

After all that, we come to the strategy for a solution.  Start with the solution of (ODE3) approaching $c$ from the left that is asymptotically $(c-x)^{1/2}$.  If we use only that, then $Q_k(c^-)=0$.  (At the end we will multiply by a constant to get our final result.)  Follow this solution to the left to the next singularity, that is approaching $c_o$ from the right.  It will look like $r_1 + r_2(x-c_o)^{1/2}+r_3(x-c_o)+\dots$ for some constants $r_1, r_2, r_3$.  Now consider solutions approaching $0$ from the right.  Using only the two basis elements asymptotically $1$ and $\log x$, following them to the right until we approach $c_o$ from the left, we can choose a linear combination so that we get $r_1$ and $r_3$ from before: $r_1+r_2^*(c_o-x)^{1/2}+r_3(x-c)+\dots$.  We want the same $r_1$ and $r_3$ as from the right, but $r_2^*$ is probably not the same as $r_2$.  This way we get $Q_k(c_o^+)=Q_k(c_o^-)$ and $Q_k(0^+)=0$.  So that all boundary terms cancel as desired.

Now we still have a constant factor to set.  If $\int_0^c U(x)\;dx$ turns out to be nonzero, choose that factor so that $\int_0^c U(x)\;dx = 1$.  Then (as noted at the beginning) we will have $A_n = \int_0^c x^n U(x)\;dx$ for all $n \ge 0$.  Another thing we have to hope for is that $U(x)$ turns out to have constant sign: The way we constructed it, we have $U(x)>0$ near $c$, but we have to hope it turns out to be nonnegative everywhere.

I will see if I can get Maple to produce some pictures.  I'm doing fine from $c$ going left to $c_o$, and from $c_o$ going both ways, but Maple seems reluctant to do (ODE3) from $0$ going up.

**added**
I am no expert on numerical ODEs.  But here is what I get.  Starting at the right, using the solution of (ODE3) with $U(x) = (c-x)^{1/2}+O((c-x)^{3/2})$ as $x \to c^-$, when I reach $c_o$ it looks like
$$
U(x) = 1831.7 - 5769.99(x-c_o)^{1/2}-13916.8 (x-c_o)+O((x-c_o)^{3/2})
\qquad\text{as } x \to c_o^+
$$
Then, starting with the soution satisfying
$$
U(x) = 1831.7 + 0.000103 (c_o-x)^{1/2}-13916.8 (x-c_o)+O((c_o-x)^{3/2})
\qquad\text{as } x \to c_o^-
$$
we end up with $0$ on the $(\log x)^2$ term:
$$
U(x) = O(\;|\log x|\;)
\qquad\text{as } x \to 0^+
$$
The graph seems to be positive everywhere!  So we merely need to divide by the integral.

Here is a plot.  (Not very informative.)
[image: plot]

Here it is near the point $c_o$:

[image: near c_o]

Comment: I estimated the integral using 1000 points.  It is between 751 and 824.  From the asymptotic formula at OEIS, we see it should be $2^{5/4} c \pi^2 \approx 797.4$.  I take this agreement as an indication I did this right.

Comment: Yes I think so, even with no numerics. Indeed I think I could turn the argument in my answer into a regularity result for the measure that solves the moment problem. 
Therefore, assuming Suvrit's existence proof, it follows that the measure whose moments are the Apéry numbers, does admit a density satisfying the third order EDO that I wrote. Thus, no wonder that the numerics suggest that there is such a solution.

Comment: Moreover, from this point of view,  the boundary conditions in my answer should be sufficient to determine the solution $w$ just looking at the point $c$,  arguing by exclusion, since as I showed a base of solutions is $u_1^2$ $u_1u_2$ and $u_2$ &cetera.